# Does anyone know where i can find more information about It's Just a Theory?

Tags: party

I met a bloke at a pub and he asked if i would like to play test a game he was working on. I really enjoyed it, but forgot to get the details of where i could find more information about it. Can anyone help me? I think it is going to be on kickstarter at some point this year.

For reference Its just a Theory is A card game where you use cards to construct conspiracy theories while other attempt to steal them. It had a party game vibe to it.

Comment: It is possible if he was having you playtest that the game hasn't been released yet, and thus probably is hard to impossible to find info on (especially if it isn't made by a big publisher)

Comment: It was a group of independent games developers, so you are probably right, i guess i will just have to keep and eye out for it poping up on kick starter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try Google?

A little searching revealed this : http://www.itsjustatheorycardgame.co.uk

Although it looks like all you can do is sign up for an alpha at the moment.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I tried looking them up on board game geek just encase and turns out they have a page for those who are interested https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/206903/its-just-theory

Makes no mention of when it will be on kickstarter though.